# How to determine particular page types for a wagtail default search?

Tags: python, django, search, wagtail

The regular wagtail search, included by default, searches over all pages of the project. How can i determine particular Pages for the search indexing?

Answer (score 2):

When searching, you can filter a Page queryset through any of the [queryset methods](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/queryset_reference.html) and then run `search` on it. So, for example, to search all pages underneath the page `blog`:

```
blog_index = Page.objects.get(slug='blog')
results = Page.objects.descendant_of(blog_index).search("my query")
```

Comment: but if i have to query only over 2 page types wich don't have parent or child pages, how should i build the query?